# How to use libraries in Clojure in LightTable

Tags: clojure, lighttable

I have the following Clojure code in LightTable

```
(ns exercise
  (:require [clojure.string :as str]))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (def str1 "Hello world")
  (str/includes? str1 "world")
)
```

When i try to run it i get the following exception:
`clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: str/includes?`

Am i importing the library wrong or is something else wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using an old Clojure version. [`includes?` was added in 1.8](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.string-api.html#clojure.string/includes?).